# Get control over Stock Android browser via adb shell or other way

Tags: stock-browser

I have to test web page in Android Stock Browser. 
Testing Chrome can be done via Chromdriver. But I want to cover Stock Android Browser( Samsung devices have such).

As i couldn't find the same (driver) for Android Stock Browser, I want to run Browser via adb shell and then control web page by executing pure javascripts

Does anybody know how to do that or maybe you know some other way to achieve testing on Android Stock Browser?

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please [edit] your question and include some more details: What actions to perform, etc.